# Calling a Batch file using parameters with spaces in the path in SQL Server Agent job

Tags: batch-file, parameter-passing, syntax-error, execution

I am running a batch file from the below location in a SQL Server Agent Job step:

```
"D:\Program Files\Cincom\Control\2212\Prd\Dcls\DEV1-MIKE1_RUN_Batch_JOB"
```

I want to pass a parameter in to run an IF statement.  However, when I do this:

```
"D:\Program Files\MyProgram\Dcls\DEV1-MIKE1_RUN_Batch_JOB 1"
```

I get the **'is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'** error

Same thing with:

```
"D:\Program Files\MyProgram\Dcls\DEV1-MIKE1_RUN_Batch_JOB '1'"
```

And:

```
"D:\Program Files\MyProgram\Dcls\DEV1-MIKE1_RUN_Batch_JOB "1" "
```

I need to pass the parameter and I need to run the batch file from the given location.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the content of the batch file, or at least the relevant lines, rather than a subset of a line?

Comment: @Laf.....Sorry, let me be more clear. I am calling the above batch file from a SQL Server Agent Job as typed out above...with the quotes

Comment: Have you tried `"D:\Program Files\MyProgram\Dcls\DEV1-MIKE1_RUN_Batch_JOB" 1`?

Comment: @Laf.....dude!  Nice....that did it.  Post your answer, if you like,  and I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround the batch file full path with quotes, then specify the parameters for your batch file:

`"D:\Program Files\MyProgram\Dcls\DEV1-MIKE1_RUN_Batch_JOB" 1`